# Count the number of rectangles in this figure.

Tags: combinatorics, rectangles

Find the number of rectangles whose edges lie completely on the grid lines of following figure

[image]

The answer says

[image]

But in the answer I do not understand the part that says:

"We can count these rectangles as follows: the number of rectangles with the center of the grid lying in the
interior of its south edge is $3 × 3 × 3 = 27$ (there are three choices for each of the three other edges)"

Can anyone please explain to me how they got this answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's counting the number of rectangles for which the center of the grid is *strictly* within the south edge (the strictly part confused me at first too). In that case:

- there are three ways to pick the left endpoint of the south edge (any of the first three red point on the central horizontal line);
- independently, there are three ways to pick the right endpoint of the south edge (any green point);
- and independently, there are three choices for the height of the rectangle (blue arrows).

[image]

Comment: Can you please state in the figure which points you are selecting for each case you stated

Comment: @Manthanein fine. see picture.

Comment: Thanks a lot...